# fail2ban ssh login waiting time after failure

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, configuration, fail2ban

This is what I want to do: 
If you login with ssh and fail 3 times then you have to wait for 30sec to try again..

4 times = 60sec

5 times = 300sec

...

10 times = banned

I googled my wish and I didn't find anything useful. Maybe someone could help me out here a little bit.

I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search show that exponential increasing of the ban time was introduced in fail2ban 0.11: https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/1460/commits/6f7c9b7d0f5c637672ed215e726e5d6ace29b664

https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/config/jail.conf

```
#
# MISCELLANEOUS OPTIONS
#

# "bantime.increment" allows to use database for searching of previously banned ip's 
# to increase a default ban time using special formula, 
# default it is banTime * 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...

#bantime.increment = true
```

and a number of other `bantime.*` related options.